# Getting printf like variable changes in os commands in Python

Tags: python, shell, operating-system, command, printf

I'm not entirely sure how to express what I need, but in essence, I need for something like

```
dirname = raw_inpur("what is your dirname")

os.mkdir(os.getcwd(), %s) %dirname
os.chdir(os.getcwd()/ %s), %dirname
```

I'm not entirely sure what the proper syntax for something like this is.

Edit: Just overthinking ofc thanks

Comment: Are you asking "how can I get a directory name from the user, then create a directory with that name in the current working directory, then change the current working directory to that directory?"? I don't think you need string formatting for that. Just pass the string straight into the function.

Comment: @Kevin interesting, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: `os.mkdir(dirname); os.chdir(dirname)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `os.path.join` to build a path (in an OS-appropriate way) from two strings:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dirname))
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dirname))
```

Since paths are just strings, you can use whatever string formatting operations you want as well:

```
os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + "/" + dirname)
os.mkdir("%s/%s" % (os.getcwd(), dirname))
os.mkdir("{}/{}".format(os.getcwd(), dirname))
```

All three share the same problem, though, which is that you assume that `/` is the correct path separator.

(I'll mention the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module here as well, without getting into how to use it or where its use is appropriate.)